# Inverse[m1 m2] not equivalent to Inverse[m2] Inverse[m1], m1,m2 are 3x3 matrices, why?

Tags: matrix

I would like to use Mathematica to show that $(AB)^{-1} = B^{-1}A^{-1}$

I used

`m1 = {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, i}}
m2 = {{j, k, l}, {m, n, o}, {p, q, r}}
Simplify[Inverse[m1 m2]]
Simplify[Inverse[m2] Inverse[m1]]`

and I find that the two expressions are not the same. I have also tried

`Inverse[m1 m2] == Inverse[m2] Inverse[m1]`

which doesn't yield True

However, when I test `Transpose[m1 m2] == Transpose[m1] Transpose[m2]` the output is True. Why? How can I fix this?

p.s: the result for the expression `Simplify[Inverse[m1 m2]]` is too long, therefore I am not posting it.

Comment: You need to use "." for matrix multiplication.  For example, `Inverse[m1.m2] == Inverse[m2].Inverse[m1] // Simplify`.

Comment: I see, Thank you very much for the comment. May I ask why then the expression `Transpose[m1 m2] == Transpose[m1] Transpose[m2]` yields True?

Comment: Perhaps a clue as to why traditional matrix multiplication was not being performed is that the order should have been reversed on the RHS for your expression to be true.  For example, `Transpose[m1.m2] == Transpose[m2].Transpose[m1] // Simplify`.

Comment: Re the `Transpose` case, the property in question happens to hold either way (that is, using matrix product or element-wise product).